# Volunteering work

Tags: usa, legal, tourist-visas, work, russian-citizens

I am a Russian woman traveling to America. I am a figure skating coach. My boyfriend is a coach in America. I am planning on traveling on a tourist visa and teach students while I’m there BUT have the students pay my boyfriend for my time. Is this allowed?

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Are you going to rely on those earnings for the trip's visa application? If that is the case then the visa is going to get refused.

Comment: This isn't volunteering. Actual volunteering can be allowed under certain circumstances, but this is just plain working; the fact that the payments are routed through someone else doesn't change the basic idea that you're offering services in exchange for money.

Comment: Are there many women called Richard in Russia?

Answer (score 18):

No.

You basically trying to work while on a tourist Visa. Getting paid through a third party doesn't change that.

Comment: It's not just "not allowed", it's a serious deception that's likely to result in a ban.